# What's the best way to distribute an android app to a limited group of people without publishing for everyone?

Tags: android, software-distribution

What are some ways to distribute android apps quickly to specific people without publishing them to Google Play?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of group?
You can publish your app on Google Play as beta and invite whoever you want.
A little bit faster method (but also a little bit more complicated to final user) is upload it also as beta on Fabric Beta (https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/overview.html)

If you want it to be fast choose Fabric Beta.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a closed beta limited to a list of emails or an open one where anyone with a link to your app can install it.

Take a look at https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do that with Google Play. Have you tried HockeyApp?
**EDIT:** It is possible to use Google Play, although the people in you ur group don't need emails for HockeyApp. Sorry!